# How to first trigger ul hover AND THEN li hover event with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I have a `<ul id="list">` and `<li class="item-class">`. When user hovers over an `<li>` inside of `<ul>` I want to first trigger the `<ul>` hover and then `<li>` hover because in my particular situation the order is significant. However, jQuery first fires `<li>` hover and then the `<ul>` event - is there a way to revert this order?

Let's have an unordered list:

```
  <ul id="list">
    <li class="list-item"> Argentina </li>
    <li class="list-item"> Mexico </li>
    <li class="list-item"> Brazil </li>
  </ul>
```

and this jQuery code:

```
function bindHoverEvents() {
    $('#list').hover(() => console.log("1. List hover"),
                     () => console.log("4. List unhover"));
    $('.list-item').hover(() => console.log("2. Item hover"),
                          () => console.log("3. Item unhover."));
}
```

When user hovers over an `<li>` and then unhovers back I a want to see

```
"1. List hover"
"2. Item hover"
"3. Item unhover."
"4. List unhover"
```

in the console, however, for some reason I see this:

```
"2. Item hover"
"1. List hover"
"3. Item unhover."
"4. List unhover"
```

Here's MRE: http://jsfiddle.net/frz24w9L/

Comment: It's not jquery, it's the browser that's sending the events.

Comment: How do I alter that order or simulate it via different approach?

Comment: First of all, some background: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/) You would need to handle events in the capturing instead of the bubbling phase. But AFAIK jQuery does not support that, so you might need to use a different library, or a native implementation then.

Comment: Call the `list hover` from within the `item hover` : http://jsfiddle.net/0d5gxtv6/

Comment: Alternatively only listen on list hover and use event bubbling to determine the event target element (the item) - essentially the same but on the list instead of item

Comment: @freedomn-m this is technically correct but you're firing list hover everytime you move to a different item - list hover should only fire once and then when hovering between items it should not fire again if you know what I mean.

Comment: That's the compromise.  You could check if it's the same list if you have something to do (or check that you haven't already done it, such as adding a class)

Comment: I might switch a variable on item hover and then check whether it hasn't already been switched on list hover and finally unswitch it on list unhover maybe.